# What was the original writing in the Bible about "don't offer comments to the unwise"?

Tags: bible

Today I heard in the radio for a one-minute talk from a pastor about:

> Don't offer comments or concern to the unwise, or else they will hate you or do bad things to you.  If you offer comments or concern to the wise, they thank you for that, because they feel they can learn things from you to better themselves

I wonder what the original writing in the Bible was?  I think I did make the mistake of offering comments to anybody, and many people hate me for it. Somehow in the 80s or 90s in Silicon Valley, I found if I offered comment to people, many felt grateful about it. Nowadays when I offer comments, it is the opposite.

Comment: Was that a Christian or secular radio station,  it sound like Proverbs 23 or Sirach 22 (Sirach being something not often referenced outside of Catholic radio).   I don't know about the talking to the _wise_ part.  There's a lot more advice in the Bible about talking to fools than talking to the wise though.

Comment: (Not) Casting pearls before the swine?

Comment: The book of Proverbs contains many sayings, often in couplets, some of them vaguely similar to what is quoted in the question, but the quotation is too vague for me to match with anything in my memory or to enable me to find it using a concordance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a verse search question with all the typical problems, namely that it's quite vague and people could think of many verses which they think convey the idea you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

I read a few translations just to find one that used language that was a little closer to what you wrote and I think this version of Proverbs 9 is closest:

> 7 (Rash souls there are, godless souls, that will not be taught or trained; who makes the attempt, gets only injury and abuse for his thanks. 8 With a rash fool never remonstrate; it will make him thy enemy; only the wise are grateful for a remonstrance. 9 Ever the wise profit by the opportunity to become wiser yet; ever the godly are the best learners.)
>
> Proverbs 9:7-9 - Knox Translation

You can check out [New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/bible/pro009.htm) for the "original" Latin or Greek. The real original would be Masoretic texts written in Hebrew, I'm not sure you'll profit from reading either of those, but maybe I'm taking your question too literally.

---

Interestingly enough, the commentary on the Knox bible says "There is some reason to suspect dislocation in the text here. These verses do not fit naturally into the speech of Wisdom, who is making an express appeal (verse 4) to the foolish." which makes sense because lots of proverbs talk about avoiding dealings with the foolish, not approving dealing with the wise so much.